# Formatting input fields

Tags: html, css

Just have a quick question, I am working on a website and as you can see I have created a few input fields. Ideally I wanted all my input fields to be skewed to the far right, which they are. Unfortunately, they are overly bunched without much padding. I've tried to add a class to my input fields and add appropriate padding via the CSS, but I've only managed managed to get them to go all to the far right.

So my question is, what do I need to add so my input fields are to the far right AND spaced appropriately?

```
<form action="demo_form.asp">
    First Name: <input type="text" name="fname" class="test" required>
    <br>Last Name: <input type="text" name="lname" class="test" required>
    <br>Contact Me By: 
    <select name="contactuser" form="carform" class="test"">
    <option value="email">Email</option>
    <option value="phone">Phone</option>
    </select>
    <br>Email: <input type="text" name="email" class="test" required>
    <br>Phone: <input type="text" name="phone" class="test" required>
    <br>Zip Code: <input type="text" name="zipcode" class="test" required>
    <br>
<input type="submit">
```

CSS

```
.test {
    position: absolute;
    right: 0;
}
```

[image]

Comment: Going to be tricky with this HTML, can you modify it at all? If not, you might try `line-height` to space things out.

Comment: I can modify it, but not the in appropriate manner I want. Whenever I start messing with the CSS I end up increasing the width / space of the fields. I tried adding the fields to a DIV then adding a class, but once again I ran into the same issue. I'm not sure if it's because of my absolute; or something else

Answer (score 0):

You need to apply a `margin`.

```
input{
   margin: 5px;
}
```

[CODEPEN DEMO](http://codepen.io/Gothburz/pen/BoqdxW)

Answer (score 0):

`line-height` seems to be the precise way if you don't want to mess with changing anything.

You can just call the `form` in the CSS and add the `line-height` there or give the form a class and do the same which will be better

---

```
form {
    line-height: 30px;
}
```

This is what i tested with and it spaced things out:

Fiddle - https://jsfiddle.net/20LcL21k/1/

Comment: Yeah it does in Fiddle, for some odd reason in my code it makes the inputs expand, guess I need to debug and see whats causing that issue

Comment: Thats because you might have some other css overridding somewhere else in your css track it down. @JustinR

Comment: @SusheelSingh is right, you will need to check your styling for something that is overriding it. maybe removing the classes called `test` on the input fields and then adding a class to the form and then doing the `line-height` property. Keep us posted

Comment: Yeah I am debugging right now I'll post an update once I figure out whats overriding

Answer (score 0):

I would use

http://materializecss.com/forms.html

Or bootstrap, but material have such a nice way of doing forms